# Convert SqlServer function results into #table to Oracle syntax

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I need to convert some procedure code from SQL Server to Oracle and I'm wondering what's the best way to handle something like this:

```
SELECT * 
INTO #tmp_Dates
FROM [fn_Get_ates](@Date)
```

And then later it returns a result set from a select which does a join against this #tmp_Dates table...

So there's a few tricky parts here...

1) Can I insert into a temp table (to replace the INTO #tmp_Dates syntax, unless there is some Oracle equivalent I'm not aware of?) which is loaded directly from the results of that function call?

2) Can I then do a open refcursor later with a select that does a join to this temp table ?

What's the simplest way to handle this in Oracle?

Comment: Have you converted `fn_Get_ates`?  If so, what did that become in Oracle?  A function that returns a `sys_refcursor`?  A pipelined table function?  Something else?  You can create a global temporary table.  You may or may not be able to insert into that GTT from `fn_Get_ates` depending on how that object is defined in Oracle.

Comment: The handling of 'temp' tables is much different.  What you want in oracle for a 'temp' table is called a 'global temporary table'.  A global temp table is a special table that is shared among users but each session can only see its own data, and the data will not persist when the session terminates. You can certainly SELECT INTO it.

Comment: Justin, that function was converted as a pipelined table func, like so: RETURN fn_Get_Dates_.tmp_Dates_type PIPELINED